# DMA error on start without AC

Tags: linux, gentoo

I installed funtoo on surface pro 2. All works good except situation when you're booting tablet on battery power. In this case I'm getting error bellow every 20 sec and tablet doesn't react on keypress, touch, doesn't log anything. `fsck` says there is no errors with disk.

```
EH complete
exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x50000 action 0x6 frozen
SError: {.PHYRdyChg CommWake }
failed command: WRITE DMA
cmd ca/00:20:f0:0f:c4/00::00:00:00:00:e3 tag 15 dma 16384 out
res 40/00:00:00:00:00:/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
statys: {DRDY}
```

Kernel: sys-kernel/debian-sources 4.8.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a power saving issue

If you have TLP try to disable it here `/usr/sbin/tlp`.

Comment out

`# set_sata_link_power $1`

More info you can find in following [discussion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171883&p=16)

(I know this is mac related discussion but can be useful for finding a solution for your setup)

Comment: Thank you, it helped me.